# How to queue in RESTful Service. Jersey?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, resteasy

Is there an implementation for queuing requests or responses in Jersey (or RESTEasy)?

How can a Jersey client queue requests before sending them?  Do we have to handle this situation ourselves?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is que request?

Comment: @AndreiI. Thanks for your attention. In JMS, messages can be qued and send them. Like JMS, is there any implementation of REST API to do like JMS ?

Comment: No, but you can use JMS for that: just extract the data that you need from the HTTP request, and push them on JMS.

Comment: FYI, in American English, it's 'queue', not 'que'. That might be throwing some people.

Comment: I think you mean **"batch"** requests as sending queues does not make any sense on this abstraction level.